# How to enable new textbox based on dynamic checkbox value selection using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, vb.net

I am creating dynamic checkbox with text using VBHTML and jQuery. There total 5 checkboxes creating dynamically. My requirement is how based on one of the checkbox selection need to enable new textbox using jQuery. Please help me how to achieve this. Please find my code which will generate checkbox dynamically.

```html
 <table>
<tr>
 <td>
@Code
    For Each item In Model.EmployeeList
    Dim itemName = item.Text
    @<input type="radio" name="DeptDetails" id="@itemName" class="cbxEmpDept" />
           @<span>@item.Text</span>
            @<br />
            Next
End Code
              @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Employee, New With {.style = "display: none;"})
                    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="trOtherDept" class="hidden">

                <td>Other Department</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.OtherDepartment, New With {.maxlength = 50, .required = "false"})</td>

            </tr>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

 if ($("#Employee").val !== '') {
            
            var data = $("#Employee").val();
            $.each(data.split('|'), function (_, val) {
                if (val.length > 1) {
              
                    $(':input[name="' + val + '"]').prop('checked', true);
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

Comment: to me it looks like you could have multiple elements with the same id `Employee`, if so then it's a no no . ID must always be unique

Comment: I am using different id for each selection of checkbox which is dynamic. You can see my code-@<input type="radio" name="DeptDetails" id="@itemName" class="cbxEmpDept" />

Comment: Is there any other alternate solution . Please help me.